# How to setup a context local object in python flask with werkzeug?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-login, werkzeug

I am trying to set up a context local in flask with werkzeug similar to flask-login's "current_user" object. I looked in the [source code where it is defined](https://github.com/maxcountryman/flask-login/blob/3eb30a2ceb507a5e1e171844f213d799d1158e73/flask_login/utils.py#L347) but am not able to replicate it and the [werkzeug documentation](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/local/) on the "LocalProxy" class used is not helping. The information I intend to access with this context local will similarly to the "current_user" object be accessed using the information in the user's session. My question is basically how to set up an object very similar to the "current_user" object.